# Issue with GitLab CE edition (creating Random Contributors)

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I installed GitLab CE edition running in a docker on my CentOS with LDAP logins.
Everything works fine, I am able to create groups, members, projects, etc.

I then used HTTPS and pulled a project repository to my Visual Studio.

[Git Connection Cloned (.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhkt7.png)

So far so good. I made some changes and then committed->pushed to GitLab, it asks for my username and password and then pushes to the GitLab repository.

Good, this is how GitLab works.

Now, the problem is when I change the Git Global settings in Visual Studio to some random Username and Email address [Git Global Setting (.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuAz7.png) it still updates my repository and lists this random user as a contributor.[Project Contributors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCCIc.png).

I am a bit confused and have been searching everywhere for a day to solve this issue. I might need to chuck the GitLab project if this issue cannot be solved.
Can someone help me with this?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this isn't standard behavior... You're committing code as a different user. What would you rather have happen?

Comment: @Scrambo, I don't have that user as a member of my private repository. Also, if I want to enter username and email of a different user, it should ask me for a password of this user, but it is not and still commits. :|

Comment: You went through the set up for ssh keys / access tokens correct?

Comment: Yes. I did that.
Strange thing is that if I go to Repository -> Commits, it commits using the original author name(first author). but the project-> details and Repository->Contributors have this new author

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty so I think I know what's going on.

You've set up either the SSH Token or Access Keys to be able to push / pull from Gitlab, and are using them in Visual Studio. I'm pretty sure visual studio is caching those, and using them when you try pushing as a "different" user. That's why it's showing up in the 'Commits' sidebar as the original author.

You might want to try making commits from the command line, or some other tool that doesn't know about your Tokens, and see if that works instead.

Comment: Hey @Scrambo, I tried with Eclipse and as it asks for Username and Password, there was nothing to worry about. Haven't tried with the command line yet as I primarily depend on Visual Studio.

Comment: Glad that it worked out for you! Now you know it's working as intended :)

Comment: But it still doesn't solve my issue with Visual Studio.  :(
My intuition is that, 
as GitLab is a distributed environment, all the commits I am doing is internal/local but when I try to push it to the repository, then the actual authentication process is invoked.
So, anyone can be a contributor but the repository push is authenticated with the author credentials and this can be viewed in the Activity tab of the project.